# How to give permissions to a specific root folder for a group of users?

Tags: permissions, group-policy

I have a folder located at **`/software`** which I want to **make it read/write/exec to a group of users**. The idea is that this folder will have common software installations, maintained by users from the same group. As an **example** this is what I was trying to do:

```
$ ls /
[...]
drwxr-xr-x 29 root root 555 Feb 18 18:31 software
[...]
```

If we go inside `/software`:

```
$ ls /software

drwxrwxr-x   2 user1 THEGROUP 26604 Feb 22 12:42 bin
drwxrwxr-x   2 user2 THEGROUP  4702 Feb 22 12:40 el6.3
drwxrwxr-x   2 user3 THEGROUP   236 May 26  2015 java-tools
drwxrwxr-x   3 user4 THEGROUP    30 Mar 26  2015 perl
drwxrwxr-x   2 user5 THEGROUP 11313 Jul 28  2015 perl-scripts
drwxrwxr-x   2 user6 THEGROUP  4893 Oct 29 12:30 python-scripts
drwxrwxr-x   2 user7 THEGROUP  1174 Sep 30 12:06 shell-scripts
```

For the sake of simplicity in the example do not care about things other permissions because I edited myself.

Notes:

- user[1-7] should be able to read/write/exec in every folder inside `/software`
- user[1-7] should be able to create new folders inside `/software`

How to achieve this? 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

- Create a new group
- `chgrp` the directory to this new group.
- Set permissions for group writeable
- Add all relevant users to the group.

All done.

The first step might depend on your distribution, but there is typically an `/etc/group. Edit it in your favourite text editor.

Then `chgrp THEGROUP /software` and `chmod g+rwx /software`

Adding users to a group can be done by editing `/etc/passwd`. This is best done carefully and there are nice tools for this (e.g. vipw)

Last items: New groups are only effective **after** a user logs in again. Secondly do you want items below /software also to have the same permissions. If you do look at the sticky bit for directories.

Answer (score 0):

First set the owner and group for the directory by following command

```
chown -R user:group [directory]
```

Then give the group full access over directory

```
chown -R -g+xwr [directory]
```

Viola, done.